# I'm trying to automatic fill the login for twitch using the selenium library in C# on the .NET framework, but the browser is not supported

Tags: c#, browser

I'm trying to do an automatic fill login on the website "twitch" through the selenium webdriver in C#, but when I click the login button, it says that the browser is not supported. What do I need to do?

This is the code in C# (on .NET framework, Windows Forms):

```
//this is a controller when the button "login" on the form is clicked (like btnlogin_click)
if (txtclientid.Text.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Client_id is required!");
    return;
}

string url = "https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" + txtclientid.Text + "&redirect_uri=https://barrycarlyon.github.io/twitch_misc/authentication/implicit_auth/&response_type=token";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--silent");


IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

try
{
    IWebElement usernamefield = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-username"));

    if (usernamefield != null)
    {
        usernamefield.SendKeys(txt_username.Text);
    }

    IWebElement passwordfield = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password-input"));

    if (passwordfield != null)
    {
        passwordfield.SendKeys(txtpassword.Text);
    }

    IWebElement buttonlogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class ='ScCoreButton-sc-ocjdkq-0 ScCoreButtonPrimary-sc-ocjdkq-1 ccqkQH gmCwLG']"));
    buttonlogin.Click();

    MessageBox.Show("Ok!");
    driver.Quit();
}
catch (WebDriverException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q3xI.png)

No more error of "browser not supported"